# C++ - Is there a way to create alias for field

Tags: c++, c++11, alias

Is there a way to create alias for class/stuct filed in C++11 ?
What I mean

I've got class

```
class Vector4
{
    public:
        float X,Y,Z,W;
}
```

I got an alias

```
typedef Vector4 Color;
```

Is there a way to create aliases for Vector4 X,Y,Z,W fields to work as Color R,G,B,A ?

Comment: No macros please, especially none with short names like `R`, `G`, `B` and `A`. Don't propose such cancer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define Vector4 like this, using anonymous unions (without anonymous structs, though they are a common extension).

```
typedef struct Vector4
{
    union{float X; float R;};
    union{float Y; float G;};
    union{float Z; float B;};
    union{float W; float A;};
} Vector4;
typedef Vector4 Color;
```

If you cannot redefine Vector4, you might instead just define a layout-compatible standard-layout class and use the dreaded `reinterpret_cast`.
That works because standard layout classes having layout-compatible members are compatible.

```
struct Color
{
    float R, G, B, A;
}
```

Standard quote:

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>   — has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
>   — has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
>   — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
>   — has no non-standard-layout base classes,
>   — either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with
>   non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
>   — has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.
>
> A standard-layout struct is a standard-layout class defined with the class-key struct or the class-key class.
>   A standard-layout union is a standard-layout class defined with the class-key union.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `alias` for a member variable in the way like below:

```
template <class Base, class Type, Type Base::*field>
struct Field {
   operator Type () const { return  base->*field; }
   Field& operator = (const Type& v) { base->*field = v; return *this; }

   Base* base;
};
```

So, you can have `Color` type like this:

```
class Color {
   Vector4 v;
public:
   Color() : v{}, R{&v}, G{&v}, B{&v}, A{&v} {}
   Field<Vector4, float, &Vector4::X> R;
   Field<Vector4, float, &Vector4::Y> G;
   Field<Vector4, float, &Vector4::Z> B;
   Field<Vector4, float, &Vector4::W> A;
};
```

Of course this `Color` type is no longer simple alias to `Vector4`...

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
class Vector4
{
    public:

        Vector4 : X(0), Y(0), Z(0), W(1), R(X), G(Y), B(Z), A(W) {}

        float X,Y,Z,W;
        float& R;
        float& G;
        float& B;
        float& A;
};
```

But then, you have to implement copy constructor and copy assignment operators that do the right thing.

A better alternative will be to access them through a member function.

```
class Vector4
{
    public:

        Vector4 : X(0), Y(0), Z(0), W(1){}

        float X,Y,Z,W;
        float& R() { return X ;}
        float& G() { return y ;}
        float& B() { return z ;}
        float& A() { return w ;}

        float const& R() const { return X ;}
        float const& G() const { return y ;}
        float const& B() const { return z ;}
        float const& A() const { return w ;}
};
```

Comment: Nice `flaog`s, where do i get them? And copying classes with references in them is ... really icky.

Comment: @Deduplicator the `floag`s are gone. As for the rest... let me just say that its an option.

Comment: I think returning `float const&` instead of just `float` hasn't any pros.